# Python scatter plot with numpy-masked arrays

Tags: python, numpy, plot, scatter

I'm stuck trying to mask data for a scatter plot.  All data seems to plot.

I'm using numpy arrays as shown in the snippet below.  I'm thinking that perhaps I cannot mask on the "c" array.  I can't seem to find any documentation for doing this.  I'll try with the "s" array.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

```
yy = NP.ma.array(yy)
xx = NP.ma.array(xx)
zz_masked = NP.ma.masked_where(zz <= 1.0e6 , zz)
scatter(xx,yy,s=15,c=zz_masked, edgecolors='none')
cbar = colorbar()
show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Works for me.  Each call to scatter() gets its own colorbar since each scatter()'s colors are normalized to its own data.  Which version of matplotlib are you using?

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y = x**2
z = y
z_masked = np.ma.masked_where(z > 0.5, z)

plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=15, edgecolors='none')
plt.colorbar()
plt.scatter(x+1, y, c=z_masked, s=15, edgecolors='none')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I realized that I forgot to change the zz array to a numpy array. 
zz = NP.ma.array(z)  When I make this change is works fine.  My mistake.  Thank you for your reply Matt.